# Question About the Logic of my Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Okay, I am working on the following relatively simple problem:

> Let $f(x) = |x-3| + |x-1|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Find all $t$ for which $f(t+2) = f(t)$.

So, if $f(t+2)=f(t)$, the is equivalent to $|t+1| = |t-3|$. Thus, if this holds, one can square both sides and arrive at $t=1$. So, this value of $t$ is a necessary condition, but prima facie it isn't the only value. To show sufficiency, could I let $t = 1 + \epsilon$, plug it into the above equation, deduce that $\epsilon = 0$, and conclude that $t=1$ is the only value? Would that go into showing this is the only value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When squaring both sides of an equation you can't lose solutions you could only get extra *false* solutions. Since $t=1$ satisfies $|t+1|=|t-3|$ that means $t=1$ is not a *false* solution and is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your work already shows that if there is a value of $t$ such that $f(t+2) = f(t)$, then $t=1$. To show sufficiency, you need to show that $f(1+2) = f(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need square both sides:

$$|t+1|=|t-3|\Leftrightarrow t+1=\pm(t-3)$$

But

$$t+1=t-3\to1=-3$$

which has no solution, so

$$t+1=-t+3\to t=1$$

So, $1$ is the only one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Noting wrong with breaking into cases.

|t+1|=|t-3|

Case 1: t+1 and t-3  both have same parity.

Then t+1=t-3 which is impossible.

Case 2: they have opposite parity.

The t+1=-(t-3)=3-t.  So t=1.

That's the only possible solution.